# how to handle vars that do not exist in a vue js template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue.js templates I have numerous instances of

```
{{ jobs[0].stages[0].node.name }}
```

and similar.  If a job does not have any stages - then the entire template will fail to load and vue.js admin gives me the following warning.

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined"
```

Is there a way to handle this more gracefully so for example if the stages or node does not exist - the template continues to load and this value is replaced with 'N/A' or something similar?

Im hoping the solution can be in the template itself rather than some complicated js (i'm new to js so its' all complicated to me)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I'm going to base this answer on the fact that you have something like that :

```
<div>{{ jobs[0].stages[0].node.name }}</div>
```

What you can do is using the `v-if` directive  :

```
<div v-if="jobs[0].stages && jobs[0].stages.length">{{ jobs[0].stages[0].node.name }}</div>
<div v-else>N/A</div>
```

Here is the documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

If *want* to do this in the template it can be done, but doing so is fairly ugly:

`<div>{{ jobs[0] && jobs[0].stages && jobs[0].stages[0] && jobs[0].stages[0].node.name }}</div>`

You'll need to add more or fewer `&&` conditions depending on how paranoid you'd like to be about the existence of the nested properties. E.g. if you think either all of the data are there or the stages array is null/undefined, you could write it like this:

`<div>{{ jobs[0].stages && jobs[0].stages[0].node.name }}</div>`

Instead, I'd recommend using a computed property to apply the necessary guards so your template isn't a mess. The commonly used function for fetching a possibly nonexistent deep property is [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) from [lodash](https://lodash.com/). You can just import `get` without importing all of `lodash` as shown in this example:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ stageName }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import get from 'lodash/get';

export default {
  props: {
    jobs: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    stageName() {
      return get(this.jobs, '[0].stages[0].node.name', 'missing name');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Note that the last argument to `get` is the default value. In this case`'missing name'` will appear if one or more of the properties is missing.

Comment: question about this last solution..  I currently already have my props defined as props: ['jobs'],  do i still need to reference in stageName as this.jobs?  or can i just use jobs

Comment: what is 'lodash/get';

Comment: (1) Yes, you need to reference your prop as `this.jobs` in your script. (2) Install lodash with `npm i lodash`. Importing `lodash/get` means: "look for the get.js file in `node_modules/lodash`. It's a way to import just that file instead of the whole library, which keeps your output bundle small.